# String length routine in assembly as a substitute for strlen in C++

Tags: c++, winapi, assembly

I am facing certain problems with strlen right now(there are many cases where I read files and the string is not zero terminated). So I was thinking of making an assembly routine to calculate the length of my strings. What I would do is just go backwards from the end of the string until I encounter my first character and then calculate the length of the string. In fact I already have one that I wrote some time ago when I was writing assembly programs.

Now, I would like to know, is there any reason why I shouldn't do this? Any particular advantages that I would be losing out on?

Another alternate would be just make each member of my character array to null. I could do this in assembly 4 bytes at a time, or even through a simple for loop.

Keep in mind that I am talking about considerable size arrays[64k]. Considerable in the length that the processing has to be really quick, since I need to display the file as soon as the user selects it.

EDIT:
To clarify, by saying that I know that I know the length of the string, I mean:

```
char* buffer = new char[length];
```

I know `length`. But when I fill this buffer, I do not know the exact length up till which it has ascii characters. When I use `strlen`, it does not give me the current length. Basically the `length` can be 500, but there can be only 5 valid characters inside it and the rest 495 could be garbage values.

Comment: "I would go backwards from the end of the string until I encounter my first character."  If you know where the string begins and ends, why not just use subtraction to compute the string length?

Comment: Tagged as `C++`, I will ask why you aren't using `std::string`.  Also, your description seems to indicate that you know the "end" of the string, but not the beginning ("go backwards until I encounter my first character") makes it really hard to follow exactly how you get into a situation where this would be useful.  How do you know the end?  How do you know when you reach "my first character"?  If you know the start and the end, then the length is simply `len = end - start`.

Comment: "there are many cases where I read files and the string is not zero terminated" Have you considered using something to read the files that actually does NULL-terminate the string? Or even better, if you know where the string begins and where it ends... you *already* know its length.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis That won't work if you have multi-byte characters and want to count them rather than the bytes. That said, since the OP didn't say that, I've the same question.

Comment: Unclear what value assembly is going to add here--you could do that in C just as easily.

Comment: @JonHanna: `strlen` counts _bytes_, not multibyte characters.

Comment: @ninjalj Exactly, so if what they wanted was to count the multi-byte characters...

Comment: @Chad
I know the size of the memory allocated for my string. However I don't know the actual number of valid characters(in a particular ascii range).

Comment: Can you avoid using raw character pointers?  Can you move to `std::string` or (less desirable) `std::vector<char>`?  Where are you getting your strings that aren't `NULL` terminated?  Any chance to change that (Which appears to be the root cause of your issues)?

Comment: Bytes are bytes. Unless you employ some complex algorithm that can tell the difference between actual text and randomly initialized memory, there's no way to know where the "text" stops and the unwritten part begins. What kind of file reading functions are you using that don't tell you how much text they actually read?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Now, I would like to know, is there any reason why I shouldn't do this?

Yes. If you already have the end byte of the string and its beginning, then you *know* it's length:

```
const char *begin = //beginning.
const char *end = //last byte of string.
ptrdiff_t stringLength = (end - begin) + 1;
```

The +1 is because `end` points to the last byte of the string. If `end` were one-past the end, you wouldn't need the +1. There's no need for any routine to calculate something you already know.

Note that this assumes that the string is ASCII or some other single-byte-per-character encoding. If you're using a Unicode encoding of some kind (UTF-8, UTF-16, etc), then you'll have to do scan the string to figure out how many codepoints it is.

Of course, if it is a Unicode encoding, then the question of what you mean exactly by "length" needs to be addressed. The "length" could be "number of codepoints," "number of distinct graphemes," or even "number of code units in the encoding."

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But unfortunately this is not what I'm looking for, and I apologize for framing the question incorrectly. I have edited my question to make it a bit more clearer.

Comment: I went with the second approach,  and now strlen works just fine. Thanks for you answer though.